# Regex replace in between two words

Tags: regex

Example text:

> This is my car, I don't like it, because it is slow. This is my car, SomeRandom24324<>, it is slow. This is my car, how about you and me..., because it is slow.

I want to remove everything in between "This is" and "is slow".

I tried `(?<=This is)(.*?)(?=is slow)`, but it only removes first occurrence and I get:

> This isis slow. This is my car, SomeRandom24324<>, it is slow. This is my car, how about you and me..., because it is slow.

Rest of occurrences are still there.

As you understand I want to have only:

> This isis slow. This isis slow. This isis slow.

PS: Any good book to learn regex?

Comment: You'll have to use the global flag. `s/(?<=This is)(.*?)(?=is slow)//g` should do it

Comment: C# dot net, more characters so i can comment.

Comment: Adam Smith I am trying in notepad++ for test, and it doesn't find it.

Comment: Works for me in Notepad++, exactly as written: (?<=This is)(.*?)(?=is slow)

Comment: https://regex101.com is a good test pad for regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is fine. I would try enabling the dotall modifier to force the dot across newlines as well.

```
String result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?s)(?<=This is).*?(?=is slow)", "");
```

As far as learning regular expressions, I would begin here: [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) — [RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com/)

Comment: Here's a working demo which produces the correct result. http://ideone.com/guGJBs

Comment: basically in the code i had `(?<=This is)(.*)(?=is slow)` which gave me totally wrong result........... couldn't see it for 30 minutes, really? doh o_O

Answer (score 1):

The regex is fine. You need to tell whatever you put that regex into (some `replace` call, probably) to replace all matches, not just one. That is not part of the regex, but a flag to the replacement instruction/call/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this can depend on the language you are using. In perl I would use the substitute function which uses regexes, eg. $line=~ s/regex_with_2_groups/"$1 whatever-u-want $2"/g, but in java I might use String.replaceFirst() or String.replaceAll and in python re.sub(). An approach is to match '(2save1)toRemove(2save2)' and output "group1 whatever-u-want group2".

Great references are Mastering Regular Expressions and Regular Expressions Cookbook.  See http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for regex deatails of all major languages that have them and software for testing and analyzing regexes and http://www.regexr.com/ has a free online tool for learning, building and testing regexes.